# Pytroch clamp for complex values

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to use clamp but it isn't working because I have a mix of complex and real values. Is there something that works the same as clamp but for real and complex values? I've tried looking some up and haven't gotten anything other than clamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [HardTanh](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.Hardtanh.html#torch.nn.Hardtanh) with a setup like below

```
for key, bounds in self.coefficient_bounds.items():
    min_value, max_value = bounds
    m = torch.nn.Hardtanh(min_value, max_value)
    # the input needs to be a tensor so we have to convert
    # custom_pauli_coefficients[key] to a tensor
    input = torch.tensor(custom_pauli_coefficients[key])
    custom_pauli_coefficients[key] = m(input)
```

Comment: What would it look like to clamp said values? Clamp ensures values fall within a continuous 1D range, your values are 2D. You could clamp the magnitude or a single component?

Comment: Basically after trying to clamp the values and getting the complex number error, I just kinda moved past it. So I'm honestly not entirely sure if doing the magnitude would work here, might have to check that out!